# PIVOT function in returns all zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, pivot

I have a table like below:

```
TestCaseID  |  currentResultVerdict
    1                Passed
    2                Failed
    3                Blocked
    4                Blocked
    5                Inprogress
    6                Passed
    7                Passed
```

I want to produce result like this:

```
Passed | Failed | Blocked | Inprogress
  3         1        2          1
```

I used `PIVOT` query like below:

```
select  *
from
(select TestCaseID, currentResultVerdict from R_4_TestCases) As SourceTable
PIVOT
(
count(TestCaseID)
for currentResultVerdict in (['Passed'],['Failed'],['Blocked'],['Inprogress'])
) As PivotTabe
```

My output is this:

```
'Passed' | 'Failed' | 'Blocked' | 'Inprogress'
  0           0          0            0
```

Why am I getting zeros?

For ease of reading I have not included other columns in my table

Comment: You shouldn't include the single quotes inside the square brackets. It should be like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5c20b/5/0. `['Passed']` would match a string starting and ending with a single quote

Comment: @MartinSmith Thats it!. Thanks for your help. Removing the single quotes now brings back desired result.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `pivot` you can achieve the same result with conditional aggregation:

```
declare @tmp table (TestCaseID  int,  currentResultVerdict varchar(50))
insert into @tmp
values
 (1, 'Passed')
,(2, 'Failed')
,(3, 'Blocked')
,(4, 'Blocked')
,(5, 'Inprogress')
,(6, 'Passed')
,(7, 'Passed')

select 
     sum (case when currentResultVerdict='Passed'     then 1 else 0 end) as Passed
    ,sum (case when currentResultVerdict='Failed'     then 1 else 0 end) as Failed
    ,sum (case when currentResultVerdict='Blocked'    then 1 else 0 end) as Blocked
    ,sum (case when currentResultVerdict='Inprogress' then 1 else 0 end) as Inprogress
from @tmp
```

Result:

[image]